# Map Lead Source to the Account Source when converting the lead to an Account/Contact

Tags: workflow, lead-conversion, field-mapping

We're running into some issues where we want to have the lead source come across as the account source when the lead is converted to an account. I figured this would be an easy thing to do, well, because it should be.

What options do I have here? I was looking into having a workflow rule take care of this, but that doesn't seem possible. Unless I'm completely missing something here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write trigger on lead update event. You can track if the trigger is newly converted using isConverted field in lead. If it is newly converted, copy the lead source value to account field.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Apex triggers. Is there a good tutorial you could recommend?

Comment: Checkout links - https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_qs_HelloWorld.htm, https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_context_variables.htm,